# UITableView footer view doesn't animate if I set it programmatically after viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController. The UIViewController has three instance variables:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var loadingIndicatorFooterView: UIView!
var searchAgainPromptFooterView: UIView!
```

This table is for showing search results. Sometimes I want to show `loadingIndicatorFooterView` (paginating results), sometimes I want to show `searchAgainPromptFooterView` (no more results to be shown).

My `loadingIndicatorFooterView` is a spinning image of a wheel and the rotation is implemented thusly:

```
class SpinnerView : UIImageView {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(image: UIImage(named: "Spinner"))
        rotateInfinitely()
    }

    func rotateInfinitely() {
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 2 //Minus can be Direction
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

I initiate and store both `loadingIndicatorFooterView` and `searchAgainPromptFooterView` in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` function. If I set `tableView.tableFooterView` to be `loadingIndicatorFooterView` in `viewDidLoad` I do see the wheel spinning. But I don't set `tableView.tableFooterView` for now, so it's `nil`.

Later when I perform a search, in my search function I have this line:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = loadingIndicatorFooterView
```

And I do see the wheel, **but it doesn't spin.**

This is my code to instantiate the `SpinnerView` and store into `loadingIndicatorFooterView` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
loadingIndicatorFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 50))
let loadingIndicator = SpinnerView()
loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
loadingIndicatorFooterView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
// < add constraints >
```

Answer (score 0):

the class spinner can be the next:

```
class Spinner: UIViewController {
    var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)

        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        spinner.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(spinner)

        spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

you should create your spinner, see this timer DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 12) {

```
func createSpinnerView() {
        let child = Spinner()

        self.view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 100)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 12) {

            child.willMove(toParent: nil)
            child.view.removeFromSuperview()
            child.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
```

and your viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.createSpinnerView()
}
```